How Hilbert space is a topological space?
I'm struggling with definitions. I go from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space:

A Hilbert space is a real or complex inner product space that is also
a complete metric space with respect to the distance function induced
by the inner product.

reading all links. "induced" links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology:

a subspace of a topological space X is a subset S of X which is
equipped with a topology induced from that of X called the subspace
topology[1] (or the relative topology,[1] or the induced topology,[1]
or the trace topology).[2]
Definition
Given a topological space ( X ,
τ ) and a subset S of X
, the subspace topology on S  is defined by

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definitions

As this definition of a topology is the most commonly used, the set τ
of the open sets is commonly called a topology on X .

Questions:

Is definition quoted at the beginning complete for Hilbert space? It looks to me what follows in wiki are explanations of terms which are explained in links of the given definition.

Is link for "induced" in the definition correct?

if Yes to (1) and (2), how one goes from definitions of topology (via sets) to distance induced by inner product? How is it proven Hilbert space is a topological space (I've found neither https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space nor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space mentioning that in definitions).



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question is similar to: Does an Inner Product Always Induce a Metric?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


You don't go from definitions of topology (via sets) to distance, but the other way around.


@Crostul, the QA you linked does not mention topology. If "induced" is not formal thing related to topology, then it might be the answer, but question 2) of my post asks about that.

@ploosu2, how should I understand link of "induced" then? How is it defined?

Linking the word 'induced' to the suspace topology is unfortunate, because here we are not dealing with that.
Instead the way the inner product 'induces' (in the sense of 'gives rise to') a metric is the following (which is a standard construction in linear algebra):

The inner product gives rise to a norm by $\|x\| := \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$

Any norm on a vector space gives rise to a distance function (metric) $d$ by $d(x, y) := \|x - y\|$


You can look up the definition of norm on Wikipedia to see what properties it must have so that you can check a) that the metric from 2) does indeed have the three properties of metric and b) that the norm defined in 1) is indeed a norm.
EDIT: this is how you get the metric. This is also explained in the linked answer. The other part of information you seem to be missing is that/how every metric (distance function) on a set turns that set into a topological space. I assume this is explained in the wikipedia article on complete metric spaces you linked to, but in short:
Let $X$ be the set with distance function $d$. For each $x \in X$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we can look at the set $B(x, r) = \{y \in X : d(x, y) < r\}$ of points at distance less than $r$ form $x$. Sets like these are called open balls. The collection of all open balls (so of all radii around all points) form a basis of a topology and hence generate a topology, which is the topology we are talking about here.

I try to correct wikipedia when I can. Do you confirm changing link of "induced" to definition of the norm will make definition of Hilbert space better? Will it be complete this changed way?

I was looking in Wikipedia to see if there is a place that addresses this issue more directly and perhaps this is the best place to link to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Relation_of_norms_and_metrics

it even uses the word induced

Thanks. I plan to take a pause for several hours just in case e.g. you come with even better ideas and then change it.

At point 1. the norm must be $|x|= \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$.

aargh, yes you are right

@gpassante, I went to sources mentioned in wiki, "Rudin W. - Real and complex analysis" additionally stipulates "non-negative" [square root].

@Martian2020 that is correct, as norms are always non-negative. I am however pretty sure that this is already implicit in the notation, i.e. that (we are now just talking about ordinary high school math in ordinary $\mathbb{R}$) the symbol $\sqrt{y}$ not just means "some solution $x$ to $x^2 = y$", but "the unique non-negative solution $x$ to $x^2 = y$" (and that the other solution (if it exists) is therefor called $-\sqrt{y}$.

@Martian2020 - See the Vincent comment. This is a universally accepted convention, as is well known.
